# Can I use multiple RF433 modules at the same time?

Tags: arduino, rf

I'm talking about these guys:
[image]
Will having multiple RF433 transmitters and receivers active synchronously cause any communication problems?

Could I tweak something(be it software or hardware) to make it so that handshaking is available?

Comment: Simple answer is no.

Comment: @Andyaka Darn it. Could you possibly explain why and are there any alternatives you can think of? Thanks!

Comment: Think along the lines of one transmitter transmitting 8 codes in sequence, with 8 joysticks connected to it. Each car responds to only one code...

Comment: The 433.92 MHz modules are not designed to occupy a particular portion of that allocated band so spectrally they will likely overlap but, even if you could pick and choose transmitters that didn't overlap the receivers have no ability to be selective towards transmitter A or B.

Comment: The use-case of the 433.92MHz modules is to implement a fully packeted protocol on top of them.  Your message should include an identifier unique per vehicle.

Comment: @insta So...In other words, it is possible to communicate individually if I include an identifier unique per vehicle?

Comment: @TrepidClaw0601: somewhat uniquely. All vehicles will receive it, you just need the firmware on those vehicles to ignore packets that aren't ID'ed for them :)

Comment: Apart from brief historic experiments, RC toys went from HF/VHF right to the cheap 2.4 GHz solutions that are also around a dollar.  Those 433 MHz regenerative radios don't have the selectivity or the data rate needed for responsive *digital* control, and would only get slower if you tried to multiplex 8 vehicles worth with coordination and worse still with uncoordinated transmitters.

Comment: @ChrisStratton In other words, the RC cars would be laggy and would not work well with 433MHz radio modules?

Comment: @ChrisStratton: you can easily get 115kbit over 433MHz, and if a packet is 32 bits (6 bits identifier, 3x 8 bits channel values, 1 parity bit, 1 stop bit), you can get over 50 updates per second to all 64 cars this trivial scheme could access.

Comment: @insta You can't get that kind of data rate out of the typical $1 regenerative receiver that is commonly sold for 433 MHz.  You may perhaps get it on those frequencies, with something else (Si446x ?) - it's just going to cost you more than a fully digital 2.4 GHz solution, which is also in the $1 module range and offers 2-way handshake that the comparably-priced-to-hobbyists 433 MHz solutions do not.  Also allowed power levels may be lower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are *a lot* of 433MHz modules out there, so "RF433" can mean many different modules and so it's difficult to answer properly.

Some of those modules allow to tweak the frequency a little. If your module does this, it *may* be possible to put each car in a separate frequency.

Some other modules apply [spread spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spread_spectrum) techniques to improve frequency usage, tough it isn't very common on 433MHz modules. If yours does, either FHSS or DSSS, then you can have "channels" that appear as noise to the other channels.

If you don't have those features, you'll have to apply some software protocol to avoid collisions. Be it some sort of [TDMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_division_multiple_access)-like or [CSMA/CA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSMA/CA)-like scheme, you'll need two-way communications (some 433MHz modules are one-way only).

If you have the simplest of modules, single-frequency one-way only, it can possibly be done, if your baudrate is fast enough to allow for a lot of errors for your actual data rate. Even then, you'll have to be very smart and employ a lot of redundancy and [robustness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_(computer_science)) and probably some sort of [FEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_error_correction) and random timing to make sure all receivers get their data, without error and in time.

Comment: While it would be technically possible to create a modern 433 MHz system, in practice it is not done, and 2.4 GHz is used instead, where chips that permit good data rates and band sharing are inexpensively available (originally created for wireless mice).  That may be as much driven by regulatory allowances as technical, but it's going to be a far more effective path.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, indeed! While 2.4GHz is usually a better option due to higher data rates and better in-chip features, it doesn't always have the same range of a 433MHz module without an amplifier. I didn't suggest it because I sticked to the question and presumed the OP already had those modules.

Comment: It's not about one frequency vs. another but rather about the performance of the commonly available solutions for each.